# Request Scope Logger for TypeORM in NestJS

Tags: logging, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS app and the logger is injected with Request scope so I can add a correlationId to every logged message, so I can see every log message that belongs to the same request. The logger for TypeORM on the other hand can only be initialized once at startup. Is there a way to have a logger in TypeORM with NestJS's dependency injection and Request scope?

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found any workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

The anwser for us was nestjs-cls.
Upside: You have access to your correlation-ID anywhere at all times.
Downside: Sometimes you have to use it „directly“ without DI (with typeorm this is the case for example).

It uses node.js asyncLocalStorage Feature with which you access to data shared inside the same Promise chain. Since node.js is single-threaded this works very well in situations like a Nestjs request.